# Use jQuery to find the label for a selected control or textbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want a bit of jQuery code that will allow me to find the label for a control when I click on the textbox... so in my HTML I have this:

```
<label id="ctl00_WebFormBody_lblProductMarkup"  for="ctl00_WebFormBody_txtPriceAdjustment">This Is My Label Value</label>

<input type="text" style="width:29px;" onclick="alert('label value here');" title="Here is a title" id="ctl00_WebFormBody_txtPriceAdjustment" maxlength="3" name="ctl00$WebFormBody$txtPriceAdjustment">
```

So, when I click on my textbox, I want (for example) to do an alert... with the text that is within my label - so in this case it would alert "This is my label value"

Hope that makes sense :)

Answer (score 57):

Use the attribute selector `[]` like `'[for="'+  this.id  +'"]'`, where `this.id` is the *ID* of the currently `focus`ed `label`

```js
$("input").on("focus", function() {
   const labelText = $('label[for="'+ this.id +'"]').text();
   console.log( labelText );  
});
```

```html
<label for="inp">This Is My Label Value</label>
<input  id="inp" type="text">

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Id go with this one but it looks like you are using asp.net web forms so use the clientID of your actual control:$('<%=txtPriceAdjustment.ClientID%>').click(function(){...etc. This will make your code more robust in terms of getting the rendered control ID

Answer (score 3):

In a HTML code like this one:

```
<label for="input-email">Email</label>
<input type="text" name="input-email" value="" />
```

You can find the label content like this:

```
$('label[for="input-email"]').html();
```

Comment: The for attribute on the label tag should correspond to the id attribute on the input.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#ctl00_WebFormBody_txtPriceAdjustment").bind("click",function(){
    alert($("label [for=" + this.id + "]").html());
});
```

or possibly

```
alert($(this).closest("label").html());
```

depending on your markup you may just be able to select the next or previous siblings too.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('input[type=text]').focus(function(){
     alert($('label[for=' + $(this).attr('id') + ']').html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#ctl00_WebFormBody_txtPriceAdjustment').click(function() {
  alert($('#ctl00_WebFormBody_lblProductMarkup').text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it with javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function displayMessage()
{
alert(document.getElementById("ctl00_WebFormBody_lblProductMarkup").innerHTML);
}
</script>

<label id="ctl00_WebFormBody_lblProductMarkup"  for="ctl00_WebFormBody_txtPriceAdjustment">This Is My Label Value</label>

<input type="text" style="width:29px;" onclick="displayMessage()" title="Here is a title" id="ctl00_WebFormBody_txtPriceAdjustment" maxlength="3" name="ctl00$WebFormBody$txtPriceAdjustment">
```