# Hide label at specific attribute

Tags: jquery, html, css

Trying to hide label when user inputs text in the input textbox.

I have the label set within the textbox with absolute positioning, and have successfully made it possible to hide the label when the textbox is `:valid` with css.

However, `:valid` isn't valid in IE8 so I'm trying to code out some jQuery to have the same desired effects.

Note: Customized framework with php so I just can't simply add attributes to html elements. JQuery is the only solution.

As translated, HTML:

```
<div>
   <label class="required" for="input1387821">First Name</label>
   <input name="data[Contact_Form][first_name]" required="1" value="" type="text" class="required-field required" id="input1387821">    
</div>
```

jQuery (What I have attempted):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("input").focus(function(){ 
        var id = $(this).attr("id");

        $("#"+id).keyup(function(){
            if(($("label").attr("for")) == id)
            {                  
                //This label where the for attribute is equal to "id" .hide()            
            }

         })       
     })
 })
```

Comment: Dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455049/use-jquery-to-find-the-label-for-a-selected-control-or-textbox

Comment: More sounds like you are looking for placeholder attribute even IE8 doesn't support it (you could search for polyfill) and anyway placeholder isn't label substitute. That's said, you'd have better imho to just let IE8 handling it differently, not trying to hide the label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("input").keyup(function(){
         if ($(this).val() !== '') {
             $('label[for="'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').hide();
         } else {
             $('label[for="'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').show();
         }
     });
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9kjtvqxb/)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your posted code, you could just toggle a class, like it:

```
$("input").on('keyup', function(){
    $(this).prev('label').toggleClass('hide', !!this.value);
});
```

CSS:

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

### -DEMO-